# Convert autofac dependency injection to .net MAUI dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, maui

I am working on migrating xamarin forms application to .net MAUI application.

In xamarin froms application i am using autofac dependency injection. now i want to convert autofac dependency injection to .net MAUI dependency injection.

I want help in converting below code to maui dependency injection

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .Where(x => x.IsAssignableTo<IViewModel>())
                .AsSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your dependencies in MauiProgram.cs

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        ConfigureApp(builder);
        ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        return builder.Build();
    }

private static void ConfigureApp(MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });
}
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var viewModelAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (var type in viewModelAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(IViewModel).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(type);
        }
    }
}
```

This should register all the types that implement the IViewModel interface as singletons in the service collection of the MauiApp builder.

Dependencies registered in MauiProgram.cs, will be available throughout your .NET MAUI application.

Check out this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am getting exception when i implement the above one.

Comment: how to print the result of below to see which classes are registered.

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .Where(x => x.IsAssignableTo<IViewModel>())
                .AsSelf();

Comment: My apologies, I grabbed the wrong code snippet.  I have updated the answer and tested it with a couple of sample view models and a simple IViewModel interface.  Both sample view models were registered for DI.  I hope this helps.